# Unable to upload file to REST API

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests, salesforce-chatter

I have this cURL request that I want to convert into a Python Request code.

The cURL content is

```
curl -H "X-PrettyPrint: 1" 
     -F 'json={"title":"PandaTest"};type=application/json' 
     -F "fileData=@rename.py;type=application/octet-stream" 
     -X POST https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/connect/files/users/me 
     -H 'Authorization: 00Dp000000.....CqqU0.S_5r' --insecure
```

For more details of the request check the SalesForce docs it contains the HTTP request message - [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#feedElementBatch). Search for the section `Upload a file to the Files home`.

The Python counter part of it what I've written is

```
import requests

files = {
            "fileData" : open("rename.py", "rb"),
            "json" : '{"title":"PandaTest"}'
        }

headers = {
              'Authorization': 'OAuth 00Dp00000000u....n3ZGuoZK2wYJRCqqU0.S_5r',
              "Content-Disposition": "form-data 'fileData'"
          }

r = requests.post('https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/connect/files/users/me/',
                  data=files, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.text)

print data
```

My request is sent successfully but I get an error `Missing expected "fileData" binary parameter`.I have a feeling the request which I'm trying to send is not formed correctly. Where exactly did I go wrong?

I have a feeling I'm not handling the 2 `-F` in the cURL request correctly.

Comment: is fileData supposed to be the actual data of the file, or the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
"fileData" : open("rename.py", "rb"),
```

is setting "fileName" to the object that is returned when you open a file. If you would like "fileName" to be the actual contents of the file, then change the line to this:

```
"fileData" : open("rename.py", "rb").read(),
```

That will read all the bytes in the file and set "fileName" to them.